# disable lxcbr0 bridge from network

Tags: virtualbox-networking

How can i disable lxcbr0 from network?
After `ifconfig` there exist a lxcbr0.
I have checked list of lxc by enter `lxc-ls`  and there was no lxc's.
I remove lxc by `apt-get remove`.
But still have lxcbr0.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure what linux distro you have.  Under Ubuntu 14.04 server, the config is in "/etc/default/lxc-net", and change

```
USE_LXC_BRIDGE="true"
```

to

```
USE_LXC_BRIDGE="false"
```

or maybe just delete it altogether if you no longer have lxc.  Surprised that lxc didn't clean after itself.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge lxc
sudo rm -rf /etc/lxc/    # It may not be necessary
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Performed below steps to delete virtual bridge in Linux system,

1. brctl show
2. ip link set lxcbr0 down
3. brctl delbr lxcbr0